# Drawing dot diagram by reading Excel coordinates using Turtle

Tags: python, excel, turtle-graphics

This is my first time posting. I am really new to Python, literally just started a class few weeks ago. I am trying to read an Excel file, which contains (x,y) coordinates, after reading it, I will have to draw dots accordingly.

I've made a function for my dot, read the file and split them into two lists x[] and y[]. I am having trouble with passing the X,Y value from my x[] and y[] to my `dot()` function.

I've searched online for similar question but no luck, I am sure it is due to how inexperienced I am with programming. Hope to get some tips from you guys.

I have posted my code below.

Thank you so much.

```
import turtle


def dot(x, y):
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.pensize(2)
t.up()
t.goto(x, y)
t.color("red")
t.down()
t.begin_fill()
t.circle(25)
t.color("red")
t.end_fill()
turtle.done()


def a():
x, y = [], []
handle = open("SineWave.csv")
for line in handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    line = line.split(",")
    x.append(line[0])
    y.append(line[1])
    x = [int(n) for n in x]
    y = [int(n) for n in y]
i = 0
while i < len(x):
    print (x[i])
    i += 1


def b():
x, y = [], []
handle = open("SineWave.csv")
for line in handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    line = line.split(",")
    x.append(line[0])
    y.append(line[1])
    x = [int(n) for n in x]
    y = [int(n) for n in y]
i = 0
while i < len(y):
    print(y[i])
    i += 1

dot(a(),b())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems a bit of a mess, some chunks duplicated, some chunks missing.  Below is my approximation of what you're trying to do.  Unfortunately, you didn't supply any sample data so I can't actually finish the code and show what it would output:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def read_points():
    handle = open("SineWave.csv")

    points = []

    for line in handle:
        my_x, my_y = line.rstrip().split(",")
        points.append((float(my_x), float(my_y)))

    return points

points = read_points()

yertle = Turtle(visible=False)
yertle.up()
yertle.color("red")

for point in points:
    yertle.goto(point)
    yertle.dot(10)

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Once you've fitted your data to the above and get it running, you might want to read about the turtle method `setworldcoordinates()` which will allow you to adjust the coordinate system of the window to better fit the data with which you're working.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will look at this slowly.